# Different Divs for older versions of IE

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get a different DIV tag if the user is using version older than IE 10. I already know the Conditional Comment method. However that is not supported on IE above 10. 
[Conditional comments are no longer supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I have been looking for other ways but many use conditional comments and others just don't work.

I would usually avoid version specific pages, but the older versions of IE display my CSS3 content in a terrible way. So would there a be a way with Jquery to check the the version of IE and show accordingly. If this was already answered please feel free to link it to me! Sorry if it's a repeat!

Comment: Why would the conditional statements have to work in IE10, aren't you attempting to show something if it's *not* IE10

Comment: So stupid... I was thinking in the mindset that it doesn't work anymore overall... So sorry for my stupidity.